# How to link html

Tags: go

I use this library to create the GUI: github.com/Equanox/gotron
I need this when I click the html button to run a Go code with the username and password.

Do you know any way to do this? I tried to google it, but I didn't find any code related to it, maybe I searched it the wrong way.

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/Equanox/gotron"
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

var tpl *template.Template

func LinkinInit()  {
    tpl = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("tpl.html"))
}

func main() {
    // Create a new browser window instance
    window, err := gotron.New()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Alter default window size and window title.
    window.WindowOptions.Width = 720
    window.WindowOptions.Height = 485
    window.WindowOptions.Title = "Login APP"

    // Start the browser window.
    // This will establish a Go <=> nodejs bridge using websockets,
    // to control ElectronBrowserWindow with our window object.
    done, err := window.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    <-done
}
```

HTML CODE
https://hastebin.com/usitorimil.xml

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Gotron readme file

https://github.com/Equanox/gotron#communicate-between-backend-and-frontend

Backend: Handle incoming events

```
window.On(&gotron.Event{Event: "event-name"}, func(bin []byte) { 
//Handle event here 
}
```

Frontend: Send event to backend

```js
ws.send(JSON.stringify({
    "event": "event-name",
    "AtrNameInFrontend": "Hello World!",
}))
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work (I'm not very good with Javascript), it also gives me an error that I can't solve, as I said, I'm not very good with JS

The error is:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
    at sendEventClick (file:/C:/Users/Ur/go/src/main/.gotron/assets/index.html:31:12)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (file:/C:/Users/Ur/go/src/main/.gotron/assets/index.html:23:54)

I also don't know if I'm using it correctly, but I think it is this way.

I created a button and placed the event onclick with function

Comment: @Ped perhaps you should do some searching on that specific error, it seems there are many results on this site and others.

Comment: @Hinos Para Disco thanks !! I did it, I'm not very good at JS so I thought it was something related to configuration, but I saw here that it was not loaded and was sending send () without the ws loading, thanks for helping me